# Rotate, Scale and translate TextView on Image Android

Tags: android, canvas, rotation, textview, surface

I have a textview with some text. Textview have touch events, so user can rotate, scale and translate text. can anybody help me. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: what did you try so far?

Comment: Thanks but i am confused how to start this.

Comment: You can always use Animation class provided by android , do you know about it?

Comment: i know actually i have capture image then write text on captured image and that text we can rotate and scale and zoom after save it

Answer (score 0):

Yes First to convert textview in imageview after you can handle multitouch in your text.

Solution:

```
                TextView usertext = new TextView(this);
                usertext.setText("Hi Hello");
                usertext.setTextSize(22);
                usertext.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);

                Bitmap testB;

                testB = Bitmap.createBitmap(TextLayout.getWidth(), TextLayout.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
                Canvas c = new Canvas(testB);
                usertext.layout(0, 0, 80, 100);
                usertext.draw(c);

               // create imageview in layout file and declare here

                Imageview iv = (Imageview) findviewByid(your imageview id)
                iv.setImageBitmap(testB);
                iv.setOnTouchListener(this);
```

Enjoy...